# I try to write my own makefile but it doesn't work

Tags: java, makefile

```
#define the suffixes
.SUFFIXES: .java .class

#compile all java files to .class
.java.class:
        javac -g *.java

#CounterStatTester is a tester class for CounterStat
CounterStatTester.class: CounterStat.class

test: CounterStatTester.class CounterStat.class
        java CounterStatTester
```

When I try to "make test", the shell says"make: *** No rule to make target `test'.  Stop."
But I did wrote "java CounterStatTester", why it still cannot find a rule?

Comment: Makefiles can be fussy in that they want a trailing newline character on the last line, and also expect tabs, not spaces for indentation.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I did add tab before every tule line. Basically, do I have problems in the code?

Comment: The code looks fine to me - do you have the file `CounterStat.class` available when you try this?

Comment: Only java files. Why I need .class when I try this? The purpose of makefile is to compile them rightly, isn't it?

Comment: The `test` rule depends on CounterStat.class. If there is no file with that name, it will look for a rule with that name. If there is no rule with that name either, then the dependency cannot be resolved, so the `test` rule cannot be run.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I compile the CounterStat.java and now there is a CounterStat.class. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is making sure you have an empty line at the end of the file. That's as much help as I can give...

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Thank you

Comment: Why downvote the question?  Whoever did it can you explain?  Downvoting is if there is no research effort, or the question is not clear, or it is not useful.  I don't see any of these things.  The only problem I have is the title su**ks :)

Comment: My suspicion is that your makefile is not named `Makefile` or `makefile`.  If you don't use one of the default names for the makefile then you have to provide the name of the makefile on the command line, like `make -f mySpecialMakefile test`.  Otherwise, based on what you've provided here, what you typed will definitely work.  So there's something more in your environment that you've not described.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson As an aside: it's true that make's reliance on TAB characters for formatting causes problems, but we shouldn't attribute every error shown by make to issues with TAB characters; it doesn't do anyone any service.  It's clear from the question asked here that the error has nothing to do with TAB.  99.99% of the time a TAB problem results in a `missing separator` error during makefile parsing.  If some other error is seen, it's almost certainly _NOT_ related to TAB misuse.  Let's not say it must be TABs unless there's good reason to think it is.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Also, it's not true that GNU make misparses makefiles that don't end in a newline.  I checked as far back as GNU make 3.74 (released in 1995) and all versions handle makefiles without final newlines correctly without complaint.

Comment: @MadScientist Yeah, that's why I put them as comments, not as an answer. As for the newlines, I'm sure I've had that problem at some point, maybe it was another build system I'm thinking of?

Comment: Not trying to be a jerk, but even comments should be related to the question being asked.  Otherwise it's just confusing for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a LOT of instances of poor style here.  Instead of just answering the question, I will try to list them all, in order of appearance.  If you do all the things I advise, your original problem will disappear for sure.

It is OK to use "poor style" if you know what you are doing and have a good reason to do so, and have already learnt good style.  In your case, it is none of these things.

1. `.SUFFIXES` is obsolete and should not be used for new code
2. Likewise, "suffix rules" like `.java.class:` are obsolete and should not be used.
3. In any case, your `.java.class:` rule should take one `.java` file and produce one `.class` file.  Good style in makefiles, is for each rule recipe to produce one target at a time, not multiple targets.

So, you should have something like this:

```
%.class: %.java Makefile
        javac -g $<
```

4. There is no reason why `CounterStatTester.class` should "depend" on `CounterStat.class` so you should not have that rule.  "Dependence" in this case would mean, that the recipe for `CounterStatTester.class` read `CounterStat.class`.  `CounterStatTester.class` really depends on `CounterStatTester.java` (and Makefile, which is less obvious), which is already captured by the rule I showed you.
5. As I mentioned above, each rule recipe should write one target.  Since `test` is not a file, but an abstract notion, so it cannot be written, and therefore, it should not have a rule with a recipe.

The point of writing a makefile, is so you don't have to execute recipes unless necessary, saving time.  In your case, `test` does not exist at all, so the recipe would be always executed, which is pointless for a makefile.

Instead, you should have a file with a name like `CounterStat_tested` and a rule like this:

```
CounterStat_tested: CounterStatTester.class CounterStat.class Makefile
        java CounterStatTester && touch $@
```

6. Finally, a makefile should have an `all` target at the top:

   ```
   .PHONY: all
   all: CounterStatTester.class CounterStat.class CounterStat_tested
   ```

Comment: But if I delete the CounterStatTester.class:CounterStat.class, how could CounterStatTester.class know where to find CounterStat and implement it in the tester?

Comment: @FrankJoe that is a Java problem.  Java is responsible for that.  Nothing to do with Make.  Your superfluous rule is just for Make and is not telling Java anything.